# socket.connect() blocks other threads?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.6, asyncsocket

If I issue multiple socket.connect() in different threads - would a single socket.connect() make the current thread to wait for an ACK response, or meanwhile another thread would be able to issue a socket.connect()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two options "current thread waits for an ACK" and "another thread would be able to connect" are not mutually exclusive. Both are true. That's the whole point of threads that one can continue while the other is blocked.

Comment: Yes but I prefer that a thread with a `socket.connect()` call won't waste CPU time on waiting for ACK. I think there's a need for events based socket class. `select()` isn't event driven when using `connect()` so it's not so good

Comment: While thread is blocked waiting for the ACK, the scheduler won't give it any time slice. At some point, the ACK is received from the network, passed through the TCP stack and then unblocks the thread again. There is no waste of CPU cycles.

Comment: +1 - @UlrichEckhardt is right - no cycles wasted, and the connects will run in parallel.